# Остается ли ссылка в памяти, если не указывает на объект?

Tags: java, android

Например, есть такой кусок кода, не из программы, а просто для примера:

```
public class Main{
private TextView mTitle;
private List<String> items;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(false){
           mTitle = findViewById(R.id.title);
           items = new ArrayList<>();  
        }
   }
}
```

Тут есть 2 ссылки, определенного типа, и видно, что во время выполнения программы они не инициализируются. Так вот вопрос в том, останутся ли они в памяти или удалятся т.к не инициализированы ?
И вообще занимают ли они память, если пустые ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку это поля объекта, то в памяти они являются частью его структуры и будут хранится ровно столько, сколько и сам объект.
Но ссылка - это адрес в памяти, то есть число (в 32-битной системе 32-битное(4 байта), в x64 соответственно 64-битное(8 байт) - не стоит париться из-за таких издержек, пока у вас количество таких объектов не исчисляется сотнями и тысячами.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько мне известно, классы в джава, инициализируются в момент обращения к ним.

Если у вас планируется большой объём информации, который затем не понадобится, вы можете принудительно указать null на ссылку, и garbage collector спустя время удалит эти объекты из памяти.

Так же можно "подсказать" системе, что есть неочищенный мусор путем звонка System.gc();

Но это не является прямой операцией к действию, для gc, вы лишь рекомендуете проверку.

Comment: Т.е, если как у меня в коде, то они будут просто занимать память?

Comment: сама ссылка private List<String> items занимает "копейки".Всё зависит от того, сколько строк вы положите внутрь.


Для наглядности, попробуйте создать 100 000 тысяч объектов с пустым листом, а затем 1 объект где лист будет заполнен на 100 000 строк, и посмотрите через диспетчер как расходуется память.

Затем спустя время, обнулите ссылку, либо используйте item.clear();

Расход памяти должен уменьшится, спустя некоторое время.

Comment: Спасибо, понял !!